# Trouble having two images overlap each other that are resized based on percentages

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a grid of image thumbs that, when hovered over, will reveal the coloured version of the thumb. Using the following code I have accomplished that, however it only works with images that are an exact square; 1:1 ratio. If a rectangular image is used all hell breaks loose. Of course, everything could work if I explicitly specify a margin-top pixel value, but I want the thumbs to resize, thus having the width 100%;

Any tips on how I can rework my css?

**CSS**

```
ul#project-grid{list-style: none; list-style-image: none; padding: 0;}
    #project-grid li{float:left; position: relative; height:auto; margin: 0 1%; width: 23%;}

.project-thumb-container{background-color:#ffffff; margin:0 auto; padding: 12%; position: relative;}
.project-thumb-container img{width:100%; display:block; z-index:0; position: relative;}
.project-thumb-container img.colour{margin-top:-100%; opacity: 0;}
.project-thumb-container img.grey{filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */ -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Google Chrome Canary */ filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */ }
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<ul id="project-grid" class="container cf">
    <li>
        <div class="project-thumb-container">
            <img class="grey" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/project-thumb1.jpg" />
            <img class="colour" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/project-thumb1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="project-thumb-container">
            <img class="grey" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/project-thumb1.jpg" />
            <img class="colour" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/project-thumb1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="project-thumb-container">
            <img class="grey" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/project-thumb1.jpg" />
            <img class="colour" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/project-thumb1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="project-thumb-container">
            <img class="grey" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/project-thumb1.jpg" />
            <img class="colour" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/project-thumb1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="project-thumb-container">
            <img class="grey" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/test_thumb.png" />
            <img class="colour" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/test_thumb.png" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

Why doesn't margin-top:-100%; work on rectangular thumbs? I don't see why my question was voted down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using jquery to add and remove the grey class instead of using 2 images?
On my jsfiddle, I only made changes to the first 2 items: http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/NcPEw/

```
<div class="project-thumb-container">
    <img class="grey" src="yourimagesource" />   
</div>
```

the jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.project-thumb-container > img').hover(
        //over
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass('grey');
        },
        //out
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('grey');
    });        
});
```

however, if you really want just css , no js :

http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/HJmxm/1/

```
<div class="project-thumb-container">
    <img src="http:yoursource" />   
</div>
```

css:

```
.project-thumb-container img{
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */ 
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Google Chrome Canary */ 
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
}

.project-thumb-container img:hover{
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add that I have a fade in effect using jquery, which would require the use of two thumbs.

Comment: heres the code for fadein effect, still without using 2 graphics:
http://jsfiddle.net/NcPEw/1/